# asynctask in imagegetter very slow when images loading

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm parsing bbcode to html and display it inside a textview.I use ImageGetter() to display images downloaded from AsyncTask.
I dont have problem for a low number of pictures.The problem arises when the number of images increases

How do I solve the problem of slow loading with ımage getter?

here is the image parser:

```
public class URLImageParser implements ImageGetter {
Context c;
TextView container;
int width = 0;
int height = 0;

public URLImageParser(TextView t, Context c) {
    this.c = c;
    this.container = t;
    width = container.getWidth();
    height = 0;
 }

public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    Log.e("GeTDRAWABLE ", source);
    final URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();


    new AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>()  {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
            String source = params[0];
            try {
                InputStream is = fetch(source);
                Log.e("InputStream",is.toString());
                Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                return drawable;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            } 
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) { 
            int wi = result.getIntrinsicWidth(); 
            int hi = result.getIntrinsicHeight(); 
            int dimDiff = Math.abs(wi - width) - Math.abs(hi - height); 
            float scale = (dimDiff > 0) ? width/(float)wi : height/ (float)hi; 
            Rect bounds = new Rect(0, 0, (int)(scale*wi), (int)(scale*hi)); 
            result.setBounds(bounds);  
            urlDrawable.setBounds(bounds); 
            urlDrawable.drawable = result;               
            URLImageParser.this.container.setHeight((URLImageParser.this.container.getHeight()  +  (int)(scale*hi) ));
            URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();
        } 

        private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            return response.getEntity().getContent();
        }

    }.execute(source);
    return urlDrawable;
}


private class URLDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    protected Drawable drawable;

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(drawable != null) {
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

here i call `ImageGetter()`:

`URLImageParser p = new URLImageParser(mTextView, mContext);`

Comment: Instead of doing it yourself.. you can try any image loading frameworks... Here is [one...](https://github.com/novoda/image-loader)

Comment: I can try universal image imageloader and picasso .But it didnt work my app. can you give me example for image loading frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

From [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the concept of lazy loading of images. There are various jar files or open source libraries available for same purpose. Some of them are following.

1. Image Loader
2. Universal Image loader
3. AQuery

Try any one of above libraries. it will solve your problem.

Comment: Universal Image loader libray I use it like over there: https://gist.github.com/Borales/7531445 but images didnt display

Answer (score 0):

By default AsyncTasks run on serial executor. It means that while one task is in process, another wait until processing task is not finished. You should run your task on thread pool executor:

```
task.runOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

but RIGHT solution is use some of existing libraries.